# Angular, RxJS: Assign a new value for Observable that has AsyncSubject source

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to create service which contains settings that service gets from a server. The settings is used widely in the application, not in one place only:

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {
  private apiResource = '/settings';
  private settingsSubject$: AsyncSubject<Settings> = new AsyncSubject();
  public settings$: Observable<Settings> = this.settingsSubject$.asObservable();

  constructor(private jsonApiService: JsonApiService) {
  }

  public init(): void {
    this.get()
      .subscribe(settings => {
        this.settingsSubject$.next(settings);
        this.settingsSubject$.complete();
      });
  }

  public update(settings: Settings) {
    return this.jsonApiService.post(`${this.apiResource}`, settings)          
  }

  private get() {
    return this.jsonApiService.get(`${this.apiResource}`);
  }
}
```

I put loading data in `init` method and call it from CoreModule in order to get data on application starting:

```
export class CoreModule {
  constructor(private settingsService: SettingsService) {
    this.settingsService.init();
  }
```

As you can see, I use `AsyncSubject` in order to force all subscribers to wait when request will be finished.

The question is how to assign a new value when `update` function is called?
I tried to use:

```
public update(settings: Settings) {
    return this.jsonApiService.post(`${this.apiResource}`, settings)   
      .do(() => {
         this.settings$ = Observable.of(settings);
      });       
  }
```

but nothing happens. And, I don't think it's a proper way to do it.

PS. One example of usage:

```
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  public settings: Settings;
  public settingsForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private settingsService: SettingsService,
              private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.settingsService.settings$
      .subscribe(data => {

        this.settings = data;
        this.settingsForm = this.fb.group({
          corValue: [this.settings.corValue],
        });
      });
  }
}

<div *ngIf="settings">
  <form [formGroup]="settingsForm">
    ...
  </form>
</div>
```

Another usage is service:

```
@Injectable()
export class CalculationService {
  private corValue: number;
  constructor(private settingsService: SettingsService) {
    this.settingsService.settings$
      .subscribe(settings => {
        this.corValue = settings.corValue;
      })
  }
... different functions that make some math calculations and some functions use corValue.  
}
```

PS2. I can't use `APP_INITIALIZER` because my settings are user specific, so user has to login first.

Comment: You can't. The `AsyncSubject` exists so that all current and future subscribers receive the **last** value from the source to which the `AsyncSubject` subscribes. Subjects are usually used to connect observables; you are explicitly supplying the subject with values, but the effect is the same: subscribers receive the last value. If that's not the behaviour you want, a plain `Subject` is likely what you should use. Also, completing an observable signals to subscribers that there are **no further values** and, in fact, subscribers will be automatically unsubscribed.

Comment: @cartant The `Subject` was the first that I tried. I put some code in the question. There you can see that I subscribe to the `settings$` and pay attention to `ngIf` in the template. So, when I used `Subject` sometimes I didn't see the form, sometimes it was shown, I think it's because request has not finished or something else. With `AsyncSubject` I don't have such problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want instead to send values to the *`settingsSubject$`* so your subscribers on `settings$` receive them downstream:

```
public update(settings: Settings) {
  return this.jsonApiService.post(`${this.apiResource}`, settings)   
    .do(() => {
      this.settingsSubject$.next(settings);
    });       
}
```

Comment: you understand correctly... but it doesn't work... because the `settingsSubject$` was completed( and it must be completed when request finished) and next call of `next` doesn't do anything. Read about `AsyncSubject` and you will get what I mean

Comment: @user348173 Is it that you want the subscriber onNext handlers to run even after the "initial" completion?

Comment: @ Yes and no, I undesrant that I can't use `next` after completion, so I am looking for some way to say to subscribers that I have some new value.

Comment: @user348173 did you find a way for this?